# Update using JSON_TRANSFORM in HQL not working

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have requirement to update and retrieve an existing column which stores data as json.

**Database:** Oracle

**Table Column type:** Clob

**Column data:** json

I am using **HQL createQuery** to retrieve data with below query which works fine. Here **defaultValue** can be either 0 or 1. I am trying retrieve the id with defaultValue as 1 and works fine.

`"select id from MyDetails where json_value(details, '$.defaultValue') =:defaultValue1"`

Any given time only one record can have defaultValue as 1. So when a new record is created with defaultValue 1. I need to update the json property **defaultValue** of any other record as 0 if it was 1 earlier. So I am trying the below HQL query.

`"update MyDetails set details = json_transform(details, set '$.defaultValue' =:defaultValue0) where json_value(details, '$.defaultValue') =:defaultValue1"`

However the statement throws below exception

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: details near line 1, column 54 [update com.xxx.MyDetails set details = json_transform(details, set '$.defaultValue' =:defaultValue0) where json_value(details, '$.defaultValue') =:defaultValue1]`

Both the select and update query works fine when tested on Oracle SQL Developer.

Please help me with the right solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

JSON function support in HQL is currently [being discussed](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/5900) for Hibernate ORM but still not officially supported.

I'd suggest trying to use native queries for now to interact with this types of functions.